# Quickly calculate the mass center of an image (or matrix)

Tags: r

I am using imager package, and come up with the following functions:

```
vector_mc <- function(v) {
  round(sum(v * 1:length(v)) / sum(v))
}

img_mc <- function(img) {
  w <- width(img)
  h <- height(img)

  # sum of all rows
  # note that as.matrix(img) is a matrix of w rows and h columns.
  row <- rep(0, w)
  col <- rep(0, h)
  for (i in 1:h) {
    row <- row + as.matrix(img)[, i]
    col[i] <- sum(as.matrix(img)[, i])
  }

  c(vector_mc(row), vector_mc(col))
}
```

It turns out that it's quit slow. Is there better ways for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main timing problem is in the addition/update of `img_mc`. Updates like this: `row <- row + as.matrix(img)[, i]` are relatively slow in R and can usually be written faster. Also, you keep recasting the image as `as.matrix` and some time might be gained by only doing that once.

Here is an updated function that is somewhat faster:

```
faster_img_mc <- function(img) {
  IMG <- as.matrix(img)
  c(vector_mc(rowSums(IMG)), vector_mc(colSums(IMG)))
}
```

The speed gain is okay larger image sizes. For a 50x50 image (the updated function was named `f` in the test below)

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(img_mc(IMG50), f(IMG50))
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min       lq       mean  median       uq        max neval cld
 img_mc(IMG50) 425.936 457.4025 2188.54828 518.355 843.2785 146939.579   100   a
      f(IMG50)  27.475  29.8900   47.69688  33.490  54.0035    247.384   100   a
```

For larger matrices the gain appears to be around a factor 9-10.

Comment: Thanks, ekstroem. By only removing the repeated recasting, the speed gain is pretty good as I just tested with 100x100 images.  Just wondering did you also optimize "rowSums(IMG)" and "colSums(IMG)"?  Thanks again.

Comment: `rowSums` and `colSums` are part of base R and are quicker versions of `apply`. They are typically quite fast.